# Run application both as server and client

Tags: java, networking, server

I want to make my pc both server and client.
This is my code

```
import java.net.*;
class tester {
static int pos=0; 
 static byte buffer[]=new byte[100];
   static void Client() throws Exception {
    InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(3000,address);
   while(true) {
    int c=System.in.read();
    buffer[pos++]=(byte)c;
    if((char)c=='\n')
      break;
   }
   ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer,pos,address,3000));
  Server();
}                   

static void Server() throws Exception {
 InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(3001,address);
 DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
 ds.receive(dp);
 System.out.print(new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength()));
}
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {

 if(args.length==1) {
  Client();
   } 
 }
```

}

**In this I have tried to make my computer both server and client.**
I run this program on cmd as
`java tester hello` but the program keeps on waiting.**What should i do to receive message typed.?**

*If there is any amendment to be made in the code please suggest that.**Note that the aim is to make my pc both server and client.**

Comment: Why are you putting _networking at the end of each question? You can use multiple tags with the question if you mean to say that this is a networking related question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Currently your application will *either* run as the server *or* the client, depending on whether or not you provide a command line argument. To run as both within the same process, you'd want to start two threads (at least) - one for the server and one for the client.

For the moment though, I'd just start it up twice in two different command windows - once with a command line argument (to make it the client) and once without (to make it the server).

EDIT: I've just noticed that your main method will never run `Server()`. So you need to change it to something like this:

```
if (args.length == 1) {
  Client();
} else {
  Server();
}
```

(You might also want to start following Java naming conventions at the same time, by the way, renaming the methods to `client()` and `server()`.)

Then remove the `Server()` call from the end of `Client()`, and call the parameterless `DatagramSocket` constructor in `Client()` to avoid trying to be a server...

The finished code might look *something* like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientServer {

   private static void runClient() throws IOException {
     InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
     DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();
     int pos = 0;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
     while (pos < buffer.length) {
       int c = System.in.read();
       buffer[pos++]=(byte)c;
       if ((char)c == '\n') {
         break;
       }
     }
     System.out.println("Sending " + pos + " bytes");
     ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer, pos, address, 3000));
  }                   

  private static void runServer() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(3000, address);
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    ds.receive(dp);
    System.out.print(new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength()));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    if (args.length == 1) {
      runClient();
    } else {
      runServer();
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this still isn't *great* code, in particular using the system default string encoding... but it works. Start the server in one window by running `java ClientServer`, then in another window run `java ClientServer xxx`, type a message and press return. You should see it in the server window.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am unable to get to the result using 2 cmd's Please tell how i could do it.I am writing `java tester hello` in 1 window and `java tester` in another.But nothing happens

Comment: @Suhail: Well are you entering a message in the "client" app? Note that it's calling `int c=System.in.read();` which is reading from the console. Bear in mind that the console may well be buffered - so type a message and press return.

Comment: @Jon Skeet please tell what do you mean by 'press return'?

Comment: @Suhail: Press the "return" key on your keyboard. Otherwise known as "enter".

Comment: @Jon Skeet still not getting any output...  :(

Comment: @Suhail: Okay, have a look now. There were quite a few problems to fix. You should also focus on readability - use whitespace appropriately, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet nothing happening...both windows keep on waiting!

Comment: @Suhail: With the exact code I've posted? It should work... what OS are you running on?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Windows 7.I must point out that your code contains errors,though i have corrected them.This code(new one after correcting) only prints the number of bytes it is sending...One more thing if put a println statement just before `System.out.print(new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength()));
` it prints that stuff,but not the immediate line after it.

Comment: @Suhail: It had a single error - a duplicate local variable declaration, which I fixed a little while ago. It only prints the number of bytes it's sending in the *client*, but it prints what's been received in the *server*.

Comment: @Suhail: Okay, I think I know what's going on. It's printing everything but then the "\r" is probably killing it. Will try on Win7 myself and correct.

Comment: @Suhail: I just tried on Windows 7 and it worked without any changes. It did request that I unblocked the app for firewalling though... could that be the issue?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet let me verify: On 1st window i write `java ClientServer` on 2nd window i write `java ClientServer hello` and then press enter.Is that so? if yes i only get sending 2 bytes on second window

Comment: @Suhail: You write a message and *then* press enter. Read what your code is doing: it's going to send whatever you've typed before pressing enter. If you don't type any text, there'll be nothing useful to send...

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes,but when i press enter after typing message in second window both windows keep waiting without the message being displayed in first window.Then again i press enter in 2nd window(where i typed in msg)  program gets terminated with 'sending 2 bytes' written in 1st window.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am sure that you wont be getting the result too?

Comment: @Suhail: Let me make this as clear as possible: In the first window, type "java ClientServer" (without the quotes) and press enter to start the program. In the second window, type "java ClientServer xxx" (without the quotes) and press enter to start the program again. Then, *still* in the second window, type a message, and press enter. The message will show up in the first window. I suspect you've been typing the message before starting the program. The command line argument (xxx) in this case is irrelevant except for whether it's present or not.

Comment: @Suhail: Well I'm afraid I've spelled it out as clearly as I possibly can, and tried it twice on my own Windows 7 box. I don't think I can help you any further - you'll have to debug it yourself. It sounds like it's the client side which is causing problems - I suggest you pepper the program with `System.out.println` messages to show where execution has got to.

Comment: @Suhail: So what did you do differently?

Comment: @Suhail: You still haven't answered: what changed? Did you change the code, or had you not been following the instructions precisely enough?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Actually i had some misunderstanding of `System.in.read()`.After writing `java ClientServer hello` i was pressing enter,then again,,,thinking that hello will be displayed on server window.Now i wrote `java ClientServer _anything_` ,pressed enter and then wrote my message,finally pressing enter.So i was mistaken.

Comment: @Suhail: That's why I gave you *very* detailed instructions half an hour ago. Next time someone takes the time to give you detailed help, please make sure you've read their answer carefully before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: You're a a software developer.. and you don't know what is meant by 'press return'?  I'm pretty sure that's illegal.

Comment: @Suhail: That's okay - I'm glad we got there in the end. I just wish we'd got there sooner. Not to worry.