# how to communicate between client and server in java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a chat program. Now the code works for communicate between client and server via command line. But it gives an exception (java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed) while running. Please help me to fix that problem.

In a java chat program,how will the communication be implemented between client and server?

ie.

client<-->server (between server and client)

```
             or
```

client A<-->server<-->client B (server act as a bridge between two clients)

Is the 2 way communication can be implemented through a single socket?
Are there any other methods ? 
How to communicate more than one client simultaneously?

### server code

```
class Server
{
ServerSocket server;
Socket client;
public Server()
{
    try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(2000);
        System.out.println("\tServer Started..........");
        while (true)
        {
            client = server.accept();
            Send objsend = new Send(client);
            Recive objrecive = new Recive(client);
            //client.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception4 " + e);
    }
}
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        new Server();
    }
}
class Recive implements Runnable
{
    Socket client;
    public Recive(Socket client1)
    {
        client=client1;
        Thread trsend=new Thread(this);
        trsend.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois;
        Message M=new Message();
        try
        {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            M = (Message)ois.readObject();
            M.display();
            ois.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception1 " + e);
        }
    }
}    
class Send implements Runnable
{
    Socket client;
    public Send(Socket client1)
    {
        client=client1;
        Thread trrecive=new Thread(this);
        trrecive.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        Message M=new Message();
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Me(server)");
            M.strmessage=br.readLine();
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(cli    ent.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject((Message)M);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

### client code

```
class Client
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    try
    {

        Send objsend=new Send();
        Recive objrecive=new Recive();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }

}
}
class Send implements Runnable
{

public Send()
{
    Thread trsend=new Thread(this);
    trsend.start();
}
public void run()
{

    try
    {
        Message M=new Message();
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Me(client)");
            M.strmessage=br.readLine();

            Socket client=new Socket("localhost",2000);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject((Message)M);

            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
}
}
class Recive implements Runnable
{
public Recive()
{
    Thread trrecive=new Thread(this);
    trrecive.start();
}
public void run()
{

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
        Socket client=new Socket("localhost",2000);
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        Message CNE=(Message)ois.readObject();
        CNE.display();

        ois.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433378/run-application-both-as-server-and-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't close the streams in every run().

Secondly, check whether port for server which you are using is free.

Comment: I am sorry,I dont know how to check the port is free?How to find a suitable port?

Comment: now i made a chat program with 2 clients and a server control the clients.      i.e the client can chat through server.but i need to chat with more than two.then how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

**This program makes your pc both host and server.**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

 public class ClientServer {
  static byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
   private static void runClient() throws IOException {
   byte buffer[] = new byte[100]; 
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();
 int pos = 0;

  while (pos<buffer.length) {
   int c = System.in.read();
   buffer[pos++]=(byte)c;
   if ((char)c =='\n') 
     break;

 }
 System.out.println("Sending " + pos + " bytes");
 ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer, pos, address, 3000));
```

}

```
 private static void runServer() throws IOException {

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(3000, address);
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
ds.receive(dp);
String s=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
System.out.print(s);
```

}

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    if (args.length == 1) {
     runClient();
   }  else {
       runServer();
      }
 }
}
```

**also follow [this link](http://suhail3.blogspot.com/2011/03/making-single-client-and-server-using.html)**

Comment: now i made a chat program with 2 clients and a server control the clients.      i.e the client can chat through server.but i need to chat with more than two.then how to do that?

Comment: @ KIRAN you can visit (http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J6a_Networking.html)

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple places where the exception could be thrown. Without a stack trace it is difficult to state so accurately, as to the cause of failure.

But the root cause, is essentially due to the fact that you are closing the InputStream of the socket in your Receiver threads after reading a message, and closing the OutputStream of the socket in your Sender threads after sending a message. Closing either of these streams will automatically close the socket, so you if attempt to perform any further operation on it, a SocketException will be thrown.

If you need to ensure that your server and client do not shutdown in such an abrupt manner, you'll have to keep reading the InputStream (until you get a special message to shutdown, for instance). At the same time, you'll also have to keep writing to the OutputStream. Two-way communication is definitely possible, and the posted code is capable of the same (if the socket remains open).

If you have to handle multiple clients, you'll need multiple reader and writer threads on the server, each listening on an instance of a Socket returned from `ServerSocket.accept()`; in simpler words, you need a reader-writer pair listening on a distinct socket on the server for each client. At the moment, multiple clients can connect to the Server, as each incoming connection is provided its own client Socket object on the Server, that is provided to individual reader and writer threads. The main Server thread can continue to receive incoming connections and delegate the actual work to the reader-writer pairs.

Comment: Thanks......Did you mean,there is no need of "client = server.accept();" in while loop?.If so how to know a message is recived?

Comment: My bad. The while loop enables multiple clients to connect. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Are there need while loops in all run method?If so,how to get an event while getting a new message???

Comment: Did you mean the sender and receiver? If so, then yes, and you should break out of the loop once you have encountered the end of the stream (for the InputStream) or once you no longer wish to write to the stream (for the OutputStream). In the current scenario, only 1 message would be either sent in total, depending on who sends first.

Comment: now i made a chat program with 2 clients and a server control the clients.      i.e the client can chat through server.but i need to chat with more than two.then how to do that?

Comment: @KIRAN, ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

chat programms normaly have a server through which all communication goes. The reason is that other wise every client needs to know how to reach every other client. And that doesn't work in the general case.

So you'll have a server, every client registers and talks with the server, which will forward messages to other clients.

Mostly communication is done via HTTP cause this is likely to go through firewalls and proxies. You probably want to read up on long polling if you are planning for anything serious.

Comment: now i made a chat program with 2 clients and a server control the clients.      i.e the client can chat through server.but i need to chat with more than two.then how to do that?